# Is it possible to use Redis Timeseries with TimescaleDB and use Redis Timeseries as a cache for faster retreival?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use redis to cache time series data of 270 stocks. Every 2 or 3 seconds I get an array of stock changes (trades) that have just happened. I want to save this data in redis so I'm currently trying to think of the best (and most efficient) way to do so. Is it possible to use Redis Timeseries with TimescaleDB and use Redis Timeseries as a cache for faster retreival?

Comment: RedisTimeSeries is a time series data structure for Redis. You can use it *instead of* TimescaleDB. Redis is much more than cache!

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LiorKogan, however we already have postgres and want to leverage existing database and SQL and timescale works well for our use cases. And we have to cache data so we dont have to get data from database every time. Can we use redis cache for caching data from timescaleDb?

Comment: Yes, you can cache the results in RedisTimeSeries and then run sub queries in RedisTimeSeries cached data.